# c# 7.x using a short name for tuple type

Tags: c#, tuples

By using Tuples, I can massively simplify my code by replacing a lot of structs. Except there is one catch here stops me from such practice.

How to preserve the names for each item in the Tuple when creating a "using" shortcut? I have created the examples in the code below with my comments.

```
/* This way is desired because it keeps the naming for each item in the Tuple, 
but incorrect grammar for C# 7.3 */
using Employee = (string Name, DateTime StartTime, DateTime LeaveTime, 
int Id, double Payment);

/* This way is the correct grammar for C# 7.3, but I lost all the names for the items, 
and I have to use Item1, Item2 and so on.... */
using Employee = Tuple<string, DateTime, DateTime, int, double>;

public class TestFunc
{
    public Employee GetEmployee()
    {
        Employee value; // I know it is an errorous usage here.
        value.Name = "Steve"; // Just want to make an example.
        value.StartTime = new DateTime();
        value.EndTime = new DateTime();
        return value;
    }
}
```

Comment: `Tuple` doesn't provide name inference, `ValueTuple` does when you use the literal syntax. The second example has nothing to do with C# 7.x tuples. The comment above the second version suggests you are confusing the two

Comment: @john that's C# 7.x

Comment: @john, I am looking forward to C# 8.

Comment: @john, just edited the post for the wording. I am using C# 7.3.

Comment: @Aluan I was specifically referring to the value tuples usage in connection with the "using" statement, since I wasn't aware of such functionality even in 7.3. OP has amended their post to be less confusing now (it no longer seems to allude to the using syntax in the first example being correct in a different version of the language). Sorry for causing confusion.

Comment: I might be wrong I'll try it later.

Comment: It's like how `using MyInt32 = System.Int32;` has always been allowed, but how `using MyInt32 = int;` has always been a syntax error. Except that your example is actually potentially useful.

Comment: Use structs. If you want to simplify argument passing and things like that, make implicit conversions from tuples to your structs. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/implicit

Comment: It's like you're going to maximum effort to avoid an explicit class/struct, even though that's exactly appropriate in this scenario. Tuples certainly have their uses, and this certainly isn't it. You seem to confuse "simpler" with "requiring less typing". Sometimes shorter code is simpler, but by no means always. Even then, maintainability is worth a good deal as well.

Answer (score 3):

Not much more typing:

```
struct Employee {public string Name; public DateTime StartTime; public DateTime LeaveTime; 
public int Id; public double Payment}
```

Leaving aside the usual discussion about the evil of mutable `struct`s<sup>1</sup>; there's plenty that can be done to make this *better*, once you've taken this step. But this is a minimal way of doing almost what you asked for (except it really does have these named fields rather than compiler trickery).

You haven't shown all of your usage for it so you may also want to implement other constructors and [Deconstruct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/deconstruct) methods.

---

<sup>1</sup>Since if you're working with `ValueTuple`s already, you're already working with mutable `struct`s, and hopefully already wary of them.

Comment: its all compiler trickery underneath, unless you are writing machine code, then its micro-code trickery.

Comment: @Jodrell - I was referring to the fact that `ValueTuple`s pretend they have fields with specific names but if you look at them funny you might still end up having to use `Item1`, `Item2`, etc because those are the actual field names so far as the CLR is concerned.

Comment: Appreciate that, was just quipping.

Comment: The only purpose of this question is replacing structs with Tuples, which mentioned in the first sentence. Also, the structs need to implement equality / GetHashCode() manually.